# How to reference currently open dialog box?

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm creating an app using Eric4 and PyQt4.

I have two dialog boxes, one runs as a thread and the other is a standard dialog box with a label inside, which I want to change to an image.

Every time the main window thread runs I want it to change the current image displayed in the dialog box to a new image. Everything works fine except every time the thread runs it creates a new dialog box with the new image inside - I want it to change the image in the dialog box that's currently open.

Dialog box with image inside:

```
class SubWindow(QDialog, Ui_subWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

    def main(self, img):
        pic = self.imgView
        pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(os.getcwd() + img))
```

Thread which changes the image:

```
class MainWindow(QDialog, Ui_MainWindow,  threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        #some code here which does some stuff then calls changeImg()

    def changeImg(self):
        img = SubWindow()
        img.main(img)
```

I've not included all my code, only the relevant bits.

Comment: I have no idea what your code does, but it looks suspicious. Firstly, you are better of with Qt's own threading class `QThread` when it comes to interaction with GUI elements. Second, you should _not_ put GUI related stuff in different threads. All GUI code should run in the same thread as event loop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you are creating a new `SubWindow` every time you wish to change the image.  I would recommend creating the `SubWindow` as an attribute to `MainWindow` in the `MainWindiw.__init__` function:

```
class MainWindow(QDialog, Ui_MainWindow,  threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        self.img = SubWindow() # Create SubWindow once here

    def changeImg(self):
        self.img.main(self.img) # Only change the image, no new SubWindow
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it isn't working, class MainWindow runs as a thread multiple times, and it's creating a new SubWindow every time it runs.